# Find out when download stops via ASP.NET or client-side script

Tags: jquery, asp.net, download

I was wondering if anyone would suggest how to fix this little visual bug?

In my asp.net code I generate a file that a user can download. The pseudo-code goes like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
Response.BinaryWrite();
Response.End();
```

I also employ JQuery to show the animation of a spinning circle on a client-side while such file is generated on the server:

```
$(function () {
    $('#ButtonBeginDownload').click(function () {
        //When Submit button is clicked
        $('#IdSubmitSpinner').css('display', 'inline-block');
    });
}
```

And CSS for the spinner is something like this:

```
.submitSpinner
{
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 6px;
    display: none;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    display: none;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<img id="IdSubmitSpinner" alt="" src="Graphics/spinner.gif" width="28" height="28" class="submitSpinner" />
```

The code above works fine and the spinner starts spinning when the download begins, but unfortunately I can't seem to find the way to make the spinner stop spinning when the file finishes downloading. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How do you trigger the actual download to start?

Comment: Long time ago, but do you remember if you ever found a solution to this? Im stuck with the same problem

Comment: @HansPetterNaumann: I think I just let it spin. But the answer below to use Ajax is probably the way to go. See if you can find a better solution, and if so, post it here...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Ajax` calls to download the file, you can use this to detect start / stop transfer:

```
$("#IdSubmitSpinner").bind("ajaxSend", function(){ // when user request sent
           $(this).show();
     }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){ // when response ended
           $(this).hide();
     });
```

Comment: Thanks, and no I use a regular download process in the browser. How do you add that Ajax calls to it? PS. I don't want to unnecessarily complicate things just to display a spinner, if you know what I mean...

Comment: You can retrieve `plain/text` content using `jQuery` `ajax()` families functions. for example: 
`$.ajax({
    url: 'yourPageURL',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(retrievedContent) {
        // do what ever you want with retrieved content.
    }
});`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not following what you're trying to suggest. How would that help me with what I'm looking to achieve?